# Java iced tea isnt working with runescape, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, openjdk, runescape

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

This is a copy and paste from my terminal of my openjdk....I install the runescape game and when it loads it goes to automatically choose graphic settings (only button to push) I push it and the game goes black and then crashes...any one know how to fix it? I run ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Are you sur you have install correctly openjdk ?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk icedtea-7-plugin openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: i just followed your instructions and its still doing it

Comment: If you install java7 (oracle) instead of openjdk ?